# Passing 'const <class>' as 'this' -- assigning values from referenced vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have the following code:

```
typedef map<int,Node, less<int> >::const_iterator TopologyIter;
iter->second.connection = myConnection->newConnections.back();
```

`connection` here is just a struct:

```
#pragma once

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
struct NodeConnection
{
    int fd;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sockaddr_storage theirAddress; 
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int port;
};
```

newConnections is a vector:

```
vector<NodeConnection> newConnections;
```

Where NodeConnection is a tcp class (nothing fancy)

I'm getting the following error though:

```
manager.cpp:92:28: error: passing ‘const NodeConnection’ as ‘this’ argument  
of ‘NodeConnection& NodeConnection::operator=(const NodeConnection&)’ discards 
qualifiers [-fpermissive] iter->second.connection = myConnection->newConnections.back();
```

I'm more than happy to post more code if needed.. I just didn't want to bombard with a wall of unnecessary text.

Comment: The whole point of a `const_iterator` is that you can't modify the object.

Comment: This has the same problem as your other question: you can't modify values through a `const_iterator`. "Discards qualifiers" means you're trying to do something that const-correctness prevents you from doing.

Comment: Thanks! I should have just waited for answers to roll in on the other question :)  I had completely forgot I did `const_iterator`... just started copy/pasting